# Custom Message Box That Blocks

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, messagebox

How can I re-implement a modal message box in WP7.1 to display custom design?

I saw number of questions with answers, both here on SO and on the Internets as well.

However, all the solutions I saw so far was non-blocking. In my app, I sometimes use message boxes to confirm something, so I need the solution that blocks the UI thread just like the system-provided MessageBox class, i.e.

```
if( CustomMessageBox.confirm( "orly?" ) ) { ...
```

Update: decompiling System.Windows.dll from the simulator image revealed that MessageBox class is merely a thin wrapper around MessageBox_ShowCore in agcore.dll, which apparently calls MessageBoxW from coredll.dll..

Comment: @Patrick, that API in WPF-only.

Comment: i think you can get some idea from MessagePrompt control in coding4Fun.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Popup to design your own messagebox. Just like @MengMeng mentioned above, you can dive into the source code of the MessagePrompt in coding4Fun, then you can fnd out how to implement it.

Comment: That's nice implementation, however they don't do what I asked for (a function that doesn't return until user clicked something). I think eventually I'll use a TaskCompletionSource from Async CTP to implement what I want: at least I should be able to write if( await CustomMessageBox.confirm( "orly?" ) ) { ...